# Material UI table I created has extra div tags which ruin my CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

[The code that is being rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgbWb.png)
[Shows the table rendered, as you can see, once I scroll past the max width the data wont show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd4mL.png)

```html
<div>
  <table (not gonna show all the markup for this. this table holds the headers of each column. this appears when i scroll to the right past the max width)>
 </div>
 <div styel="height: inherit; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y: auto;">
  <table (not gonna show all the markup. this holds the rows of data, that dont appear past the max width)>
  </div>
```

When the code from image 1 gets rendered, the data that exists past the max width does not appear when I scroll to the right.

The table headers, however, do. Upon investigating I found the problem to be a `div` tag.

The way it's marked up when I inspect the page (HTML snippet above), the header of the `table` is wrapped in a `div` tag, and the `body` of the `table` is wrapped in another `div` tag.

The `div` tag around the body has styles `overflow-:x hidden` and `overflow-y: auto` (the `div` tag around the header has no style).

If I unset both of the overflows, the table looks exactly how I want it to look.

However, I did not code these div tags and I am not sure how they got there, I'm guessing material UI put them there. How do I change or get rid of these tags? Or is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the style/theme by `withStyles(styles)(YourTable)` like [this example](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/099920cc0e14a2ff44c5e925ddb28c376fecd599/docs/src/pages/demos/tables/BasicTable.js). 
Or, you can add a `className` to your `TableBody` and update your CSS accordingly.